# How to add a new column with the correct order in awk taking into account that the same position may be repeated

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to generate a new column with the new ranking position for a series of millionaires. The problem is that many of them have the same amount of money and when I generate a list with the order as follows: `NR>1{$0=$0", "NR-1} 1`, it doesn't take me into account if there are more than one or two millionaires with the same amount of money.

What I want to do would be for example to order something like this:

```
Name;Company;Billions    
Bill Gate;Microsoft;76
Manolo Chocolatero;Churrerias;2
Eduardo Mendoza;ED S.A;3
Juan Palotes;Circos S.A;2
```

Output:

```
Name;Company;Billions;Ranking    
Bill Gate;Microsoft;76;1
Manolo Chocolatero;Churrerias;3;2
Eduardo Mendoza;ED S.A;2;3
Juan Palotes;Circos S.A;2;3
```

Any idea how to do this with awk?

Comment: Your input and output's 3rd columns differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` allows you to use variables, e.g. one for the rank, and one for the last value. With that, you can increase the rank only if the current value differs from the last one (assuming that you sort the input previously).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes, the values are ordered. The problem I have now is that I am not able to assign the correct value to the ranking column.

Comment: Maybe `awk -F\; 'NR == 1 { print $0";Ranking"; rank = 0 }  NR > 1 { value = $3; if (value != lastValue) { rank++; } lastValue = value; print $0";"rank }'` (just from the top of my head).

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot! I was already stuck in my mind and was not able to improve my code! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\; -v OFS=\; 'NR == 1 { $(NF + 1) = "Ranking" }
            NR > 1 { ++a[$NF]; $(NF + 1) = length(a) } 1' file
```

Apply sort if they aren't sorted.